# accessing a database field of a many to many relationship through tinker

Tags: laravel, tinker

Couldn't access a database field through tinker

```
$job::find(2)->despatches->qty
```

Doesn't work

```
$job::find(2)->despatches
```

works

but i need to access the qty field of despatches

Is this possible through tinker?

Comment: Is your `qty` field on the related record, or is it on the pivot table? Also, a many-to-many relationship will always return a `Collection`, so which record in the Collection are you trying to get the qty for?

Answer (score 1):

Since `$job::find(2)->despatches` returns a collection, you have to use `pluck()`:

```php
$job::find(2)->despatches->pluck('qty')
```